# I want to generate a wsdl file from a given xml excerpt I was given to generate a WSDL file in order to develop my soap web services

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xsd, ping

`this is my XSD file`

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/tenantStandardPing" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/tenantStandardPing" elementFormDefault="qualified">
``
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        enter code here<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Security>
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>****</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>****</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <wsa:To>https://ctaau.vedaxml.com/sys2/ping-v1</wsa:To>
        <wsa:Action>https://ctaau.vedaxml.com/mode/test</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>Test_Ping</wsa:MessageID>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
        <ping:request client-reference="Customer Test Ping"
        xmlns:ping="http://ctaau.vedaxml.com/vxml2/ping-v1-0.xsd"/>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</schema>

```
````

I am getting the following error while designing this schema-> s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'schema' is invalid. Element 'Envelope' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Comment: what kind of product are you using to create your webservice? if you are using C# there is no need to create an xml schema or wsdl. Creating the web service will generate a wsdl for you based on the service and operational contracts.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you take time to _format your question properly_. It is fairly obvious that you have not reviewed what you posted. Why not take 5 minutes of your own time to correct the very obvious mistakes now?

Comment: @martijn we were using java, yeah we fortunately got it created. thanks